# Django Latin Characters do not work

Tags: python, django, encoding, decoding, latin1

I'm trying to solve this issue when importing a CSV file. I try to save a string variable that contains latin-1 characters and when I try to print them, it changes it to an encoding. Is there anything I can do to keep the encoding? I simply want to keep the character as it is, nothing else.

Here's the issue (as seen from Django's manage shell

```
>>> variable = "{'job_title': 'préventeur'}"
>>> variable
"{'job_title': 'pr\xc3\xa9venteur'}"
```

Why does Django or Python automatically change the string? Do I have to change the characterset or something?

Anything will help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your terminal is entering encoded characters; you are using UTF-8, and thus Python receives *two bytes* when you type `é`.

Decode from UTF-8 in that case:

```
>>> print 'pr\xc3\xa9venteur'.decode('utf8')
préventeur
```

You really want to read up on Python and Unicode though:

- The [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)
- [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) by Ned Batchelder
- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by Joel Spolsky

Answer (score 0):

```
"{'job_title': 'pr\xc3\xa9venteur'}"
```

The characters have been encoded into UTF-8 for you, which is pretty nice, because you don't want to stick with Latin-1 if you value your sanity.  Convert to Unicode for best results:

```
>>> '\xc3\xa9'.decode('UTF-8')
u'é'
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using print statement instead?

```
>>> variable = "{'job_title': 'préventeur'}"

>>> variable
"{'job_title': 'pr\x82venteur'}"

>>> repr(variable)
'"{\'job_title\': \'pr\\x82venteur\'}"'

>>> print variable
{'job_title': 'préventeur'}
```